# 2001 GMC Jimmy wont start?

Tags: engine, starting, gmc

Hi I have a 2001 GMC Jimmy 
it was running fine, then parked it.   it starting acting funny, sometimes would take a couple times to start, so checked my oil dipstick, it read a little high and smelt fuel in the oil, so I changed the oil and oil filter,  But not it wont start, it turns over and just dies and a puff of white smoke comes out of Carburetor.

any idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are some serious modifications to your Jimmy, it doesn't have a carb. I would suggest you have a fuel injector which is stuck open.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember your setup correctly you have a 4.3L Vortec engine. The fuel pressure regulator and plastic fuel lines commonly had issues in that engine. The regulator and lines are located inside the intake manifold and when it goes bad it floods the engine terribly. That engine has a fuel pressure port on the metal fuel line coming into the engine. Attach a fuel pressure gauge to it and see how much pressure you can build up and how long it take to bleed off. Also remove the intake tube, hold the throttle plates open and look inside with a flash light. If you see puddles of fuel then that is your problem.